# Why is the spacing so large on this equation?

Tags: spacing

I had previously asked a question on how to remove the indenting on question parts and the suggested answer was to create the command

```
\newcommand{\questionx}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \marksnotpoints
    \qformat{\textbf{Question~\thequestion} \hspace{1ex}\textbf{(\totalpoints \enspace \points)}\hfill}
    \pointsinrightmargin%
    \pointformat{\textbf{\themarginpoints}}% 
    \settowidth{\leftmargin}{(m)\hskip\labelsep}%
    \question\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\parbox{\textwidth}{#1}
}
```

However from this there appears to be a side effect which is that long equations which run over a single line now have this weird spacing between the operators as seen in the attached image. I tried to reduce the font size but that only makes the gaps around the plus signs even larger to fill in the lost space. The code for the example is

```
\subpart[3]Use (a) part (ii) to show that;

\begin{small}
$\sqrt{x(y+z)(z+x)}+\sqrt{y(z+x)(x+y)}+\sqrt{z(x+y)(y+z)}\leq2\sqrt{(xy+yz+zx)(x+y+z)}$
\end{small}
```

[image]

And for context my preamble is

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.8}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.25in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{} 
\chead{} 
\rhead{} 
\lfoot{} 
\cfoot{\footnotesize{Page \thepage \ of \numpages}}
\rfoot{}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're setting your questions inside a `\parbox`, it will necessarily be justified. And justification requires content to stretch to fill the line as needed, which happens around binary and relational operators in math mode. One way around this is to issue `\raggedright` just before setting the math content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question
  \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{This is a question

    $\sqrt{x (y + z) (z + x)} + \sqrt{y (z + x) (x + y)} + \sqrt{z (x + y) (y + z)}
      \leq 2 \sqrt{(xy + yz + zx) (x + y + z)}$
  }

  \question
  \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{This is a question
    \raggedright
    $\sqrt{x (y + z) (z + x)} + \sqrt{y (z + x) (x + y)} + \sqrt{z (x + y) (y + z)}
      \leq 2 \sqrt{(xy + yz + zx) (x + y + z)}$
  }
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Of course, `\raggedright` is a *switch* after which everything within a similar scope/group will be set with that alignment. If you want to limit the scope of this alignment, use

```
\begingroup
\raggedright
<your content>\par
\endgroup
```

Note that the `\par` (or an empty line) is necessary to "process" the alignment.